# Deleting part of a string pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab

**Background:**
I have the following pandas Dataframe:

[image]

**Objective:**
Each field in the tweet column contains tweets (duh!). I am trying to do two things:

- Delete all characters from the string before 'InSight'. So all tweets would begin '**InSight sol...**'
- Extract dates from the tweets (that are present just prior to 'InSight' and save these in a new column, named 'Date'.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried things such as `split_string = tweets_df.split("InSight", 1)` but I can't seem to write any code that is OK with splitting part of a string, but rather just a delimiter.

Any advice would be grately appreciated.

Comment: Always post your data as text and not as an image. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

pandas.DataFrame.applymap
Apply a function to a Dataframe elementwise.

This method applies a function that accepts and returns a scalar to every element of a DataFrame.

```
new_df = df.filter(['tweet']).applymap(lambda x: x[x.find('InSight'):])
dates_df = df.filter(['tweet']).applymap(lambda x: x[x.find('-') + 1:x.find('InSight')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the trimmed column back to the original column instead of doing subsetting, and also the str.replace method doesn't seem to have the to_replace and value parameter. It has pat and repl parameter instead:

example:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].str.replace("\s:00", "")

df
#   ID       Date 
#0   1  8/24/1995
#1   2   8/1/1899
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract string after `InSight` you can use positive lookahead regex

```
df['text'] = df['tweet'].str.replace('.*(?=InSight)', '', regex=True)
```

To extract the date in the provided format, use `str.extract` with positive lookbehind regex

```
df['date'] = df['tweet'].str.extract('(?<=-)(\w{3} \d{2})')
```

Output

```
                                               tweet            text    date
0  Mars Weather@Marsweatherreport-Jul 15InSight s...  InSight sol 58  Jul 15
```